# We are craving with conditional branch

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

My if sentence is very difficult to read
**ProjectController.php**

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    $cats = Category::all();
    $users = User::all();
    if(!empty($request->project_name && $request->requester && $request->user_name && $request->status && $request->requester_tell))
    {
        $view = Project::where('project_name', 'like', '%'. $request->project_name .'%')->where('project_name', 'like', '%'. $request->requester .'%')->get();
    } if(!empty($request->project_name && $request->requester && $request->user_name && $request->status))
    {   
        $view = Project::where('project_name', 'like', '%'. $request->project_name .'%')->paginate(10)->get();
    }else if(!empty($request->project_name && $request->requester && $request->user_name))
    {
        $view = Project::where('requester', 'like', '%'. $request->requester .'%')->paginate(10)->get();
    } else if(!empty($request->project_name && $request->requester))
    {
        $view = Project::where('user_name', 'like', '%'. $request->user_name .'%')->paginate(10)->get();
    } else if(!empty($request->project_name))
    {
        $view = Project::where('status', 'like', '%'. $request->status .'%')->paginate(10)->get();
    } else if(!empty($request->project_name || $request->requester || $request->user_name || $request->status || $request->requester_tell))
    {
        $view = Project::where('requester_tell', 'like', '%'. $request->requester_tell .'%')->paginate(10)->get();
    } else if(!empty($request->requester && $request->user_name))
    {

    } else if(!empty($request->status && $request->requester_tell))
    {

    } else if(!empty($request->requester && $request->requester_tell))
    {

    } else {
    };
```

I've written so far, but I want to know if there is a better way to write
I want to pull data that matches the search conditions from the DB

Originally all contain null

Comment: [empty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) takes 1 parameter?

Comment: @vivek_23 Takes some parameters in request

Comment: Does `if(!empty($request->project_name && $request->requester && ... ))` even execute? I presume it considers non-empty string as true.

Comment: Also, you check for `!empty($request->project_name && $request->requester && $request->user_name && $request->status && $request->requester_tell)` and in the query only use 2 fields/columns `$view = Project::where('project_name', 'like', '%'. $request->project_name .'%')->where('project_name', 'like', '%'. $request->requester .'%')->get();`?

Comment: That is definitively the wrong way to use `empty`. For any variable / index that isn’t actually set, this would still give you a undefined variable / index notice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a key array and loop on that array. Inside loop you can check if it's empty if not then apply the condition.

```
$relevantKeys = ["project_name", "requester", "user_name", "status", "requester_tell"];
$query        = Project::select("*");
foreach ($relevantKeys as $value) {
    if (!empty($request->{$value})) {
        $query = $query->where($value, 'like', '%' . $request->{$value} . '%');
    }
}
$view = $query->paginate(10)->get();
```

> **Note:-** I am considering static keys as request object may have other data which is not relevant for filter operation.

Comment: Too few arguments to function Illuminate \ Support \ Collection: get (), passed 0
How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Solved by deleting paginate(10)

Comment: If you need paginate then remove get and keep paginate. It should work.